# Should spring-boot-started-web have a dependency on jboss-logging?

Tags: hibernate, logging, jboss, spring-boot, logback

Spring Boot 1.1.8.RELEASE with a dependency on spring-boot-starter-web causes a dependency on hibernate-validator, which in turn has a dependency on jboss-logging.

The dependency on jboss-logging causes jboss logging to take over logging output over logback, which is also a dependency, and is the usual logger for spring-boot. At least, that is what happens to me. By logback.xml file is completely ignored even when specifying the logback.configurationFile system property at startup.

I know it is possible to exclude jboss-logging in maven or gradle, but should this really be required? Should spring-boot-starter-web specify the exclusion itself?

This is the output at application startup:

```
12:56:42,137 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider
12:56:42,145 [main] INFO  o.h.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.3.Final
12:56:42,206 [main] DEBUG o.h.v.i.e.r.DefaultTraversableResolver - Cannot find javax.persistence.Persistence on classpath. Assuming non JPA 2 environment. All properties will per default be traversable.
```

But if you remove the jboss-logging dependency with an exclude in maven, at runtime you get a stack trace from application context startup.

```
16:56:30,956 [main] WARN  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/BasicLogger
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:199) ~[spring-context-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:620) ~[spring-context-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467) ~[spring-context-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109) [spring-boot-1.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691) [spring-boot-1.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:142) [spring-boot-1.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.infor.cloud.dojo.manager.server.Application.main(Application.java:283) [infor-cloud-dojo-manager-server-20141022T1625.jar!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53) [infor-cloud-dojo-manager-server-20141022T1625.jar!/:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_20]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/BasicLogger
```

Thanks,

-Don

Comment: Yes that dependency should be there if you have hibernate-validator available (that is an optional dependency if I'm not mistaken). The redhat guys decided they needed their own logging framework. However it shouldn't interfere with your logging as it eventually will output to SLF4J which in turn logs to logback. So I suspect something else is wrong in your configuration.

Comment: Also note that at startup spring boot will have its own configuration and your config file will be loaded later in the proces. Initialization of logging is a 2 step proces. What isn't working that you expected to work?

Comment: Yes, I can see that jboss logging is using slf4j, and confirmed that, so it should be OK. Even though now we have a logging facage in front of a logging facade. Silly. The problem I have is that I cannot get logback to read the configuration file. It will only read the configuration file if it is on the classpath, even when I specify the -Dlogback.configurationFile=/absolute/path/to/logback.xml. It works OK when I put it on the classpath though. They are the same file, I just want my configuration elsewhere.

Comment: prefix with `file:` to have it load from the filesystem instead of classpath. It uses springs resource loading mechanism to load the file I guess.